# AngularJS ng-include partial html content not accessible in the respective controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have the below html

```
    <body>
        <div id="container" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
            <div id="header" ng-include src='"partials/header.html"' ng-controller="headerCtrl"></div>
            <div id="content" ng-include src='"partials/content.html"' ng-controller="contentCntrl" style="overflow: hidden;"></div>
        </div>
</body>
```

In this main.html I am loading two partial view below as

**header.html** is below as

```
<canvas id="headerCanvas"></canvas>
```

**content.html** is below as

```
 <canvas id="contentCanvas"></canvas>
```

In the headerCtrl when I write `$('#headerCanvas')[0]` I am getting `undefined`.

Not sure as of now why it is happening, please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because when you are intializing the controler the html is not loaded yet form the `ngInclude`. what you can do is to use the `onLoad` event of the `ngInclude`.

```
 <div id="header" ng-include src='"partials/header.html"' onload="onHtmlLoaded()" ng-controller="headerCtrl"></div>
```

and then in the header controler headerCtrl

```
var headerCtrl=function (){

  $scope.onHtmlLoaded(){
   // you have $('#headerCanvas')[0] here
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, though he really shouldn't be doing dom manipulation from within a controller.

Comment: Yeah that's true, but it seems to be that  he is working with canvas. He won't have much alternatives.

Comment: Of course there are alternatives. `canvas` is just a tag like any other, and directives can be applied to any tag.

Comment: Thank Jayantha and Stewie for replying. Actually my requirement is that I have a 3rd party vendor library that does all the manipulation of canvas element shown above. Doing what Jayantha has mentioned solves my problem.However, the 3rd party library exposes methods that I use to manipulate the canvas elements. So the code for manipulation should be ideally be in my controllers, as the actual drawing will be done by the library itself, correct if I am wrong and also I am new to AngularJS so apologies for typo.